# iterating over Scala collections in Java

Tags: java, scala, iterator, scala-collections

How I can iterate over Scala collections in Java?

Comment: Remember, unless no one has answered your question to your satisfaction, you should accept one of the answers given.

Comment: What? Then show us what you tried.

Comment: When I write `scala.collection.Iterator ite = e.getLastAdd().iterator();`, IntelliJIDEA show me an error: `cannot resolve symbol 'Iterator'`

Comment: Please edit your question (or start a new one) to include the code you're using. Also, make sure your Java compilation has the Scala library in the class-path. It's the file `lib/scala-library.jar` in the Scala Development Kit's base directory.

Answer (score 18):

Some example Scala

```
class AThing {
  @scala.reflect.BeanProperty val aList = List(1,2,3,4,99)
}
```

A Java client

```
public class UseAThing {
  public static void main(String a[]) {
    AThing thing = new AThing();
    scala.collection.Iterator iter = thing.getAList().iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
      System.out.println(iter.next());
    }
  }
}
```

Output

```
jem@Respect:~/c/user/jem$ java -cp /opt/scala/lib/scala-library.jar:. UseAThing
1
2
3
4
99
```

Does that help?

Comment: Any way to use java 1.5's new for/in loops?

Answer (score 3):

Get a Scala `Iterator` from the collection and use a conversion from `scala.collection.JavaConversions` to turn it into a Java `Iterator`.

Here's an example:

```
scala> val li1 = List(2, 3, 5, 7, 11)
li1: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 5, 7, 11)

scala> val ii1 = li1.iterator
ii1: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator

scala> import collection.JavaConversions._
import collection.JavaConversions._

scala> val ji1: java.util.Iterator[Int] = ii1
ji1: java.util.Iterator[Int] = IteratorWrapper(non-empty iterator)

scala> val ji2 = ii1: java.util.Iterator[Int]
ji2: java.util.Iterator[Int] = IteratorWrapper(non-empty iterator)
```

With the `JavaConversions` imported into any given scope, there's an implicit conversion that will turn any Scala `Iterator[T]` into a corresponding Java `Iterator<T>`. In the preceding example, the explicit type of the `ji1` declaration triggered the application of the implicit conversion of the initializer, `ii1`. In the `ji2` case, the type ascription on `ii1` triggers the conversion.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(Item item: JavaConverters.seqAsJavaListConverter(seq).asJava()) {
    // Do thing with item
}
```